# How to Achieve Parallel Processing using Prisma, SQL, and Node

Tags: sql, node.js, prisma

I've got a feature request for a client where they want to regenerate potentially tens of thousands of SQL records on-demand within a few seconds up to a minute or two at max.  In simple terms, they have a found set of Jobs where some cost items can be calculated based on the work done, materials, mileage, etc. and those items need to be stored/overwritten in SQL.

As a naive approach I tried various methods like Promise.all() to create a bunch of Promises to be executed in parallel, but I quickly ran into a bunch of errors in Prisma, mainly due to the db running out of connections in the pool/timing out when fetching connections, etc.

I've seen some examples ([like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgUpI_EnAQs&pp=ygUOd2ViZGV2Y29keSBwZGY%3D)) where developers use SQS queues to generate thousands of PDFs in only a few seconds.  I need something that functions exactly like this, but somehow work around the DB connection limitations.

I've tried using `Promise.all()` to execute hundreds to thousands of promises in parallel. I expected this to resolve all of the promises, but I quickly ran into connection pooling limitations/timeouts.

I've been hacking at this for a couple weeks and would really appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance!